# Reading pom version in a pipeline job if pom is not in project root

Tags: maven, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried using [readMavenPom](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) like the following to get the pom version and so for this has been working very well as the pom.xml file has been present in the root of the project directory.

```
pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
```

For some of our projects, this pom.xml won't be available in the root of the project repository instead it will be available inside the parent module so in that case, we modify the groovy script like the following.

```
pom = readMavenPom file: 'mtree-master/pom.xml'
```

There are only two possibilities, either the pom.xml file will present in the root or it will be inside the parent module. So is there a way to rule out this customization that we make every time?

Comment: For those projects which it is inside a folder these projects should be refactored...

Comment: So we have both parent / child modules and we usually compile it specifying the 'mvn -f mtree-master/pom.xml' and it works fine for us. Therefore we haven't kept pom.xml file in project root so far. Does this approach has any cons?

Comment: I would like to clone my repo and just do `mvn clean package` in the root and everything should work. Also importing into IDE's works that way best...makes it easier ...(conventions?) The cons are you need to know that you can't use the root without directly...

Comment: @khmarbaise yep that makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check if the file exists in a specific location with `fileExisits`:

```
def pomPath = 'pom.xml'
if (!(fileExists pomPath)) {
  pomPath = 'mtree-master/pom.xml'
}
pom = readMavenPom file: pomPath
```

**Bonus**: Check multiple paths

```
def pomPaths = ['pom.xml', 'mtree-master/pom.xml']
def pomPath = ''
for (def path : pomPaths) {
  if (fileExists path) {
    pomPath = path
    break
  }
}
// check that pomPath is not empty and carry on
```

Comment: @gmc, is it possible to add more file path into consideration? i.e ntree-master/pom.xml? I have tried using else if statement but it doesn't work. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: yes, I'd make a list of possible paths and loop through it until the file is found

Comment: @gmc multiple paths checking doesn't go well. Not sure why. I got "The fileExists step was called with ', the empty string so the current directory will be checked instead.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BMESSENGER/pom.xml does not exist" looks like its not checking other possibilities.

Comment: I made a little mistake, I was checking `pomPath` instead of `path`

Comment: @gmc, thanks a lot. This worked like a charm. One last question, I use this readMavenPom file to get the version number to set the currentBuild.displayName (like  https://dpaste.de/3nFv) but if the choices in the list are not available then I don't want the build to be failed saying pom.xml not found instead I would like to set the default displayName which is the BuildNumber.